# Apply a polynomial function to a large dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, apply

I am trying to apply a polynomial function to a data set. The issue I am facing is that the function was made from a smaller data set than the one I am trying to apply the function to.

How do I apply this function to the column of a larger data set ?

Here is a reproductible example:

```
set.seed(4568)
var1 <- runif(100)
var2 <- runif(100, min =10, max = 80)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2))

mod <- nls(var2 ~ b2*log((b0/var1)-1) + b1,
             start=list(b0=1, b1=0, b2=50),
             data = df1)

df1$pred <- predict(mod)

df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(runif(10000),NA))
```

I want to predict `df2$V2` by applying to `df2$V1` the function from `mod`. I tried the following code:

```
predictions <- sapply(df2, function(x){predict(mod, newdata = x)})
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What error do you get? It worked for me

Comment: I don't get any error but doing that replaces also my df2$V1 values with the predictions, which I don't understand...

Comment: So you want to predict `V2` and keep `V1`?

Comment: `predict` expects a data.frame as input, you pass a vector. Try this: `df2$V2 <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(var1 = df2$V1))`.

Comment: Yes I want to keep `V1`. Thank you Roland that works. Very simple in the end...

Comment: Btw., you need to ditch the `as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2))` construct. The proper way is `data.frame(var1, var2)`. Your approach creates a matrix which is then turned into a data.frame. That is a problem because a matrix can hold only one data type.

Comment: Ok thank you. My original object is already a dataframe so it only applies to the reproductible example here, but I'll keep that in mind !